# Como verificar se um parâmetro do tipo Integer recebido no Spring está vazio?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Eu tenho um método que vai receber vários parâmetros. Mas os parâmetros estão definidos como required = false porque não quero que seja obrigatório que eles sejam informados e também não informei um default value porque eles só devem receber algum tipo de valor se o usuário passar tal valor. Ou seja, se o usuário informar o parâmetro, ele deverá obrigatoriamente atribuir um valor a ele. Se ele não informar o parâmetro, não tem problema. Ele só não pode informar um parâmetro sem atribuir valor a ele.

No Postman, quando eu passo a URL para entrar no meu método no Java informando o parâmetro e não atribuo um valor a ele (por exemplo, quando deixo o sinal de igual vazio ou não informo o sinal de igual:)

http://localhost:8181/projeto/estado?codigoEstado=

Ele identifica como se o parâmetro não fosse passado em vez de identificar que o parâmetro está vazio mesmo eu tendo escrito o seguinte código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Ou seja, se o parâmetro informado não for nulo, mas estiver vazio, então ele vai retornar erro 400 em vez de entrar no método que executa a rotina desejada.)

Eu não posso mudar o tipo do parâmetro na linha do `@RequestParam(value = "codigoEstado", required = false) Integer codigoEstado` porque senão eu teria que alterar uma boa parte do meu projeto.

Alguém sabe o que eu posso fazer para verificar se um Integer está vazio?

Comment: Coloque o código sempre como **texto** e não como imagem. Qual o problema de interpretar "o valor do parâmetro não foi passado" como "o parâmetro não foi passado"?

Comment: Cara eu não sei se isso vai ser de muita ajuda mas você pode construir seu `if` dependendo do valor que o `System.Out.Println(codigoEstado)` retorna. O que no seu caso provavelmente será um `NullPointerException` ou 0.

Comment: Você está usando Java 8? Se sim, talvez o `java.util.Optional` possa ajudar, ao invés de usar `required = false`. Algo tipo isso: `@RequestParam("codigoEstado") Optional<Integer> codigoEstado`

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que até existe uma melhor maneira para isto, mas é uma solução: creio que seja possível você pegar o objeto `HttpServletRequest` e chamar o método `getParameterMap()`, e verificar se o parâmetro está no Map e se o valor dele está nulo. Algo assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity buscar(
        @RequestParam(value = "codigoEstado", required = false) Integer codigoEstado 
        HttpServletRequest request) {
     Map<String, String> parametros = request.getParameterMap();
     if (parametros.contains("codigoEstado") && parametros.get("codigoEstado") == null) { 
          // erro 400
     }
}
```